# In Pokémon quest I have a white star next to my slowpoke, what does the white star mean?

Tags: pokemon-quest

What does a white star in Pokémon quest mean?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this gamefaqs thread](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/240026-pokemon-quest/76661982), the white star indicates the Pokémon is shiny. A shiny is an alternate color of the original form. As seen in the two images below, a shiny Rhyhorn has a white star while a regular Alakazam does not have a star.

[image: Shiny Rhyhorn, has star]
<sub>([Image source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HEIo.jpg))</sub>

[image: Regular Alakazam, no star]
<sub>([Image source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUI0K.jpg))</sub>